# Error when accesing Razor Boolean variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have tried several tactics to use the boolean value within the JS ,but nothing works :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
       if (model.IsNew == true) {
        alert("1");
     }
</script>
```

Tried the following:

```
var IsNew = @Model.IsNew ;
var IsNew = "@Model.IsNew";
```

I keep getting the following error :

```
Conditional compilation is turned off
```

Anyone could explain why this occurs and maybe guide me to a possible solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
if ('@Model.IsNew' == 'true') {
    alert("Is New");
 }
```

Comment: you would need to do: 
  == 'True'

Answer (score 2):

That's just the VS IDE failing to understand the mix of Razor and Javascript.

Your code will work fine.